# Is it better to have HDDs on standby after a while or not for a 24/7 home office server?

Tags: hard-drive, nas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is turning off hard disks harmful?](https://superuser.com/questions/17228/is-turning-off-hard-disks-harmful)

I have a NAS with a WD Server HDD (3 years old, 1TB).

Is it better to have it running all the time, or should I put on the standby time to make the HDD shut down after a while?

It comes out of standby about 10 - 20 times a day, and it makes that weird noise when it wakes up. It did it from day 1 on so I guess its normal.

Comment: Please read our FAQ next time, this question is more suited to our sister site superuser.com

Comment: This is far too subjective to get an objective answer out of.  Ask a dozen geeks and you'll get at least 7 or 8 differing opinions of drive life expectancy vs sleep times vs whatever.  Very few of those are rooted in fact, and given discussions with peers and colleagues, and some rather extensive research on the power savings involved when you do this at scale, I can safely say that nobody has definitive proof to support any extreme of argument here.

Comment: All that said: I would be worried about the drive spinning up that many times in any given day.  That's an opinion and is simply rooted in my own superstition.  I would be attempting to lengthen the sleep times so that it at most sleeps once or twice a day.  Again, just experience and superstition talking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://superuser.com/questions/17228/](http://superuser.com/questions/17228/is-turning-off-hard-disks-harmful)