# Max read/writes to an SD card

Tags: sd-card, memory-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the life expectancy of an SD card?](https://superuser.com/questions/17350/whats-the-life-expectancy-of-an-sd-card)

I have been told this before that an SD card has a max of 10k writes and 100k reads, but I can't seem to find any information on it.

Is there a limit to the number of times you can read/write to an SD card?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on flash memory technology, which depends on the manufacturer.  Taken from the "SanDisk SD Card Product Manual":

> SanDisk SD cards have an endurance
>   specification for each sector of
>   100,000 writes typical (reading a
>   logical sector is unlimited).
>
> Therefore, extremely heavy use of the
>   card in cellular phones, personal
>   communicators, pagers and voice
>   recorders will use only a fraction of
>   the total endurance over the device’s
>   lifetime. For instance—it would take
>   over 10 years to wear out an area on
>   an SD Card based on a file of any size
>   (from 512 bytes to maximum capacity)
>   being rewritten 3 times per hour, 8
>   hours a day, 365 days per year.

Answer (score 0):

At least SanDisk gives you lifetime warranty so they probably have quite a bit trust in their products. For normal use it very likely won't matter.

But yes, Flash memory has a limited number of write cycles. Wear levelling spreads writes over the card so you won't have any hot spots that wear out too early.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest moving to another community, such as ServerFault/SuperUser.

You would be concerned with "[memory wear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory#Memory_wear)". This is a limitation not specific to SD cards alone, but to the memory technology itself, to include Compact Flash, and other SSD's, for example.

Comment: "You don't have to go home, but you can't stay here..."