# How long can SD survive being a hard disk on a laptop?

Tags: storage, sd-card

I have a laptop with small storage, so I added an sd card in my sd card slot to be an additional storage.

How long will it survive reading and writing from it ?
I intend to have a lot of design files that I work on regularly as an interior designer and architect.

I am also considering installing softwares like photoshop if I ran out of my primary storage.

How long should I expect the SD card to work?

and how can I regularly check its life?

and would not installing softwares and being content with using it for the files I use through these softwares help me extend its life ?

and how long could that be ?

And what would be better options ?

Answer (score 1):

It will last until it decides to die. This could be several years or several minutes. They are far too fragile to be used in this manner.*
An SD card should **never** be the only location for any data.

There is no way to 'check its life'. Best you can do is to know 'it's working right now'. When they fail they fail suddenly & often drastically.

A far better option would be a bigger SSD.

*I speak from personal experience. My job used to entail getting through literally thousands of SD cards a year, so I've seen their real-world failure rates first-hand.

Answer (score 0):

The life expectancy of a SD card is already addressed in this question: [What's the life expectancy of an SD card?](https://superuser.com/questions/17350/whats-the-life-expectancy-of-an-sd-card)

You cannot accurately translate this into a time, because it depends on how often files are being (re)written and their size.

You can regularly scan the SD card for errors as you would for any other storage device.  How this is done depends on which operating system you are using (not stated).  However, this will only tell you whether there are errors at that point in time or not.  There is no guarantee the SD card will not suddenly die.

The better option is to replace your primary storage with a larger capacity.