# CPU, HDD, GPU temperture monitor Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, temperature

Is there a Gnome Pannel Applet or even just software, that supports a lot of mobos and sensors? I have a AMD Phenom x4 cpu with a Gigabyte Mobo and Nvidia 9600 GPU. I tried "Computer Temperature Monitor" all that could find is my HDD temp. Any recommendations?

Thanks

Comment: This is a good point for something else I am working on: http://superuser.com/questions/681/booting-linux-off-usb-pendrives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open terminal and enter following lines:

```
sudo apt-get install sensors-applet
sudo sensors-detect
sudo reboot
```

Answer yes on all questions(it will install all dependencies and autoconfigure sensors). After rebooting right click gnome panel->add to panel->hardware sensors monitor. After that configure applet to display what you need.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it did not grab the temperature of my CPU. But it did get it for my HDD and GPU. Anything else I can do to configure it?

Comment: http://lm-sensors.org/wiki/Devices according to this wiki devs dropped support for amd k10(phenom)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Ubuntu, add Hardinfo in Ubuntu Software Centre. You will then find in Applications>System Tools a new item, System Profiler and Benchmark. Open this, and click on Sensors. This works on both AMD Phenom II x4 and x6.