# Ubuntu karmic 9.10 Live image on USB is not working

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb-flash-drive, iso-image, livecd

This is my configuration:

- 4GB HP pendrive
- Ubuntu-9.10-desktop-i386 image file for live USB install
- pendrivelinux (u910p) and ubetbootin (unetbootin.sourceforge.net)
- T61 machine

Earlier I have installed a Ubuntu live image using the two aforementioned utilities numerous times, but on a 2GB Kingston flashdrive.

Today, I am trying to install the live-image on 4GB HP flashdrive. Both of the utilities install and I can see the files in the drive. Even the wubi-installer is working. It say press "reboot" to boot in live-ubuntu. But, when I press "reboot" it does not reboot Windows 7.

Now, when I reboot and select boot-usb in the BIOS, it say "no boot record". I am making my USB bootable using the utility, and even then nothing is working out. I did this a few times.

Is 4GB USB a problem? Does anyone know how to partition my USB in 2-2GB and install it on one partition, and then use the live image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some USB drives simply don't work. I have one USB flash drive that will not boot, regardless of what I do to it. I think it may be because of the U3 crap thaty put on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can partition your USB drive with [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) before starting your sequence.
I do not think 4GB is a problem either.
You can also use the [GPartedLive](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) version.

I prefer [installing Ubuntu on the flash drive](https://superuser.com/questions/681/booting-linux-off-usb-pendrives) rather than setting up a live image.
Its more fun to use installed Ubuntu and you also get options to partition the drive on the way.