# How to execute a script while booting Linux from flashdrive?

Tags: linux

I know i can make my script run at boot time in runlevel 2 by putting it in /etc/init.d/ and creating a symbolic to it in /etc/rc2.d but thats when Linux is on hard drive.

I want to run my script from a flashdrive such that when a user plug in a flashdrive and powers ON the machine, it may start booting from the OS in flash drive and eventually executing my script.

How can I achieve such a functionality?

I have tried burning OS to flashdrive but I never succeeded in booting OS from flashdrive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [boot linux from the flashdrive](https://superuser.com/questions/681/booting-linux-off-usb-pendrives) -- does that solve your question?

Comment: Actually No it doesn't. I need a very small size linux image or something(not Karmic Koala) which I can customize such that it's init.d has myScript in it and then I may be able to burn that image to my Flashdrive. And when I boot from flashdrive myScript should run at boot up. I hope my question makes some sense.

I made a Live CD which does exactly this, using 'Finnix' (a Linux distro) but I am unable to make Finnix boot from flash drive. Their finnix-thumbdrive utility does not work at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems like two questions: how can I boot off a flash drive, and how can I run a script while its booting.

#### Flash Drive Booting

The ability to boot off a flash drive is dependent upon whether the hardware supports booting from USB. Its common on newer hardware, not so common on hardware that is two or three years old.

#### Init Script

On Debian, I use /etc/rc.local to run simple shell scripts.

For more information, check out NODOWS and Mindeb, the sites have lots of notes on creating small distribution sizes using SquashFS:

http://www.nodows.com/
http://www.mindeb.com/

Hope that helps!