# Is it possible to boot live USB with latest Kubuntu version 9.10, as is possible with Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubuntu

I see a few guides for Ubuntu on a thumb drive, but will it work for Kubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

There is one at PenDriveLinux -- [Install Kubuntu 9.10 to a Flash Drive from Windows](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/create-a-kubuntu-9-10-live-usb-flash-drive-from-windows/).
Please note that a Live USB is different from a [USB Installation](https://superuser.com/questions/681/booting-linux-off-usb-pendrives).