# Resize Linux root partition from a flash drive

Tags: linux, partitioning

I need to make my root partition bigger to add more free space. Is there a Linux version that will fit on a small usb flash drive that has the tools I need? I plan to boot a Linux distro from a flash drive in order to resize the partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the size affordable for the USB boot flash?
The [Ubuntu distribution easily fits in a 8G flash](https://superuser.com/questions/681/booting-linux-off-usb-pendrives) -- I mean an install not a LiveUSB.

If you are looking for a small LiveUSB, the [PuppyLinux](http://puppylinux.org/main/index.php?file=Overview%20and%20Getting%20Started.htm) will fit in a very small footprint (about 256MB).

Finally, if you have a sharp target, you can head straight to the [GParted Live](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) distribution.

> **GParted Live** is a small bootable GNU/Linux distribution for x86 based computers.
>   It enables you to use all the features of the latest versions of the GParted application.
>
> GParted Live can be installed on CD, USB, PXE server, and Hard Disk then run on an x86 machine.
>
> GParted Live includes additional packages, such as:
>   mlterm  - Multilingual terminal emulator (provides access to command line) 
>   partimage   - Backup partitions into a compressed image file
>   testdisk    - Data recovery tool that can help recover lost partitions
>   nano    - Text editor
>   vim-tiny    - Enhanced vi text editor
>   parted  - Partition table editor (command line based)
>   fdisk   - MSDOS partition table editor (command line based)
>   gdisk   - GPT partition table editor (command line based)

Comment: It's only 125MB. I have another flash drive that is 2GB but it can't be made bootable.

Comment: Hmm, Can you work with a LiveCD?

Comment: Yeah, the LiveCD worked.