# Not authorized to mount on persistent-USB Lucid installation

Tags: ubuntu, mount, persistent

**Background**.
I use a [persistent Ubuntu installation on a USB stick](https://superuser.com/questions/681/booting-linux-off-usb-pendrives) (16GB).
The purpose is to carry the USB flash instead of a netbook/laptop;
I usually find a laptop/pc handy close by to work with so this works great for mobility.

Now the **problem context**.
I shifted from Jaunty to Lucid short while back (a fresh-install, not an upgrade).
installed most of the packages I need from the Lucid repository.
For this I used my home computer.
Then (as usual) I returned to my laptop with the flash drive and started working with it there.

The **exact problem**.
A couple of things don't work randomly (sometimes they do, sometimes don't).

1. I cannot mount other partitions visible on my Nautilus view.

   - this includes local drives on my laptop and other USB drives
2. I cannot shutdown Lucid.

   - when I try from the panel, it returns to the login screen in a short while.

The two things happen together.
 Yet, they don't happen always -- sometimes mounts and shutdown works fine on the laptop too.
They happen only on my laptop (where I did not install this Lucid) but never on the home computer (where I installed it).

When the problem occurs,
I get a "Not Authorized" to mount error when I try to mount the drives visible in Nautilus. But, I can "`sudo mount`" them normally (I can also "`sudo shutdown`" from a console terminal). So, I conclude that something with the gnome/nautilus ability is not working right on my laptop (sometimes). I looked at the '`auth.og`' and other log files to identify what differed when things failed from when they were working -- but, to no clear indications.

I am also interested in understanding how Nautilus mounts drives from my user login.
It would help me decode what is missing in my path here.

Comment: it sounds to me like a permissions issue based on the fact that the fat32 thumbdrive (open to corrections if it's formatted otherwise).  just a thought.  you could try chainloading the iso so it should work like you're booting from USB except for the HUGE ramdrive

Comment: How does your /etc/fstab look like?  What are the permissions of the mount points?  Can you do `sudo halt`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your sudoers file is messed up?  Just an idea.

Alt+F2, then run `gksu nautilus`.  Try everything from the root file manager!

If all else fails, maybe you could try logging in as root?