# Replacing a laptop hard drive (Compaq Presario V5305WM)?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, laptop

My Compaq Presario laptop hard drive has failed (luckily I was prepared). Now I want to refurbish this machine for another use. I'm going to need a new hard drive and was wondering where I could get the cheapest model.

I don't need a big hard drive (just big enough to run Ubuntu). That means anything bigger than 15 GB's will do just fine. I need an IDE (PATA) hard drive. Where can I get the cheapest one that is bigger than 15 GBs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is motivated from your [**desire to run Ubuntu**](https://superuser.com/questions/681/booting-linux-off-usb-pendrives) on the [**Presario V5305WM**](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00783092&lc=en&cc=py&product=3231960).
<sup>The [V5000 laptop](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportMachinesLaptopsCompaq) works fine with Ubuntu.</sup>
You will probably find hard drive references however, this is a different option.

You have an [ExpressCard slot](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/ExpressCard_slot) which can take a [CompactFlash adapter](http://www.thefind.com/computers/info-expresscard-54-compactflash-card-adapter).
This lets you plug in any [Compact Flash memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CompactFlash) there and it will go in completely inside the slot
(unlike USB flash drives which stick unsafely out of the laptop frame).
<sup>Alternatively, if you are more adventurous -- and, I suggest you don't jump to this yet -- there are also [SSD drives](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820208324).</sup>

Once you get this hardware setup, you can install Ubuntu from a LiveCD straight to the memory in this slot and boot from it. That will give you a 'solid-state' memory making your laptop more mobile (the hard disk platters are not very happy with movement and shakes in the back seat of a car or the metro, for example).

<sup>Here is one [Ubuntuforums discussion on VM5305WM](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=289322), you will probably find more recent ones.</sup>

**Update**:
Here is [one reference for Compact Flash memory](http://www.flash-memory-store.com/compactflash.html).
You probably don't need extremely fast cards -- [133x and such should be good enough](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CompactFlash#Speed).

> CompactFlash IDE (ATA) emulation speed is usually specified in "x" ratings, e.g. 8x, 20x, 133x. This is the same system used for CD-ROMs  and indicates the maximum transfer rate in the form of multiplier of the data rate of an audio CD, which is 150 KB/s.

[image] <sup>KB/sec</sup>

> where R = transfer rate, K = speed rating.
>   For example, 133x rating means transfer speed of: 133 * 150 kB/s = 19,950 kB/s ~ 20 MB/s.

And, You should look for a good adapter which will not slow-down your access.
<sup>I am not too good with the adapter part, some one else here will probably help out.</sup>

Comment: What are the prices are on a CompactFlash drive? (I can't seem to find any)

Answer (score 0):

Here in Sweden you can pick up an 80 GB 2.5" IDE drive at 50€ or less. I checked a few dealers, and that's the smallest they've got. The market for IDE drives is shrinking, so most dealers just have a few options left.

You can get a 16 GB compact flash card for about the same price.