# Make "Try Ubuntu" dialog box non-interactive

Tags: ubuntu, usb-storage

I have Ubuntu 11.04 32-bit installed on a usb drive. Every time I boot the drive my work laptop Ubuntu asks me if I want to 'Try Ubuntu' without installing or 'Install Ubuntu.' I always click 'Try'

I want to know how to find the file to modify so the default is 'Try' and it never asks me.

Here are all the processes that were running before I killed the "Try" window:

```
> root      4120  2670  0 18:43 ?        00:00:00 udisks --inhibit -- /usr/lib/ubiquity/bin/ubiquity --greeter --only

> ubuntu    4134  4120  0 18:43 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/ubiquity/bin/ubiquity --greeter --only

> ubuntu    4269  4134  0 18:43 ?        00:00:00 gnome-pty-helper

> ubuntu    4270  4134  0 18:43 pts/0    00:00:00 tail -f /var/log/installer/debug -f /var/log/syslog -q

> root      4304  4134  0 18:43 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl -w /usr/bin/debconf-communicate -fnoninteractive ubiquity

> root      4306  4134  0 18:43 ?        00:00:00 log-output -t ubiquity --pass-stdout /usr/lib/ubiquity/localechooser/localechooser

> root      4307  4306  0 18:43 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/ubiquity/localechooser/localechooser
```

So I should be concentrating on debconf-communicate or ubiquity. Does any one have any clues?

Comment: What bootloader are you using, and what boot options?

Comment: I changed both linux lines in /cdrom/boot/grub/loopback.cfg (removed only-ubiquity) and it still doesn't work so I am going to have to create a new initrd for this aren't I? if so I'm in over my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a [LiveUSB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD#Preparing%20your%20LiveCD) rather than a [**persistent install**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence).
The latter is more suitable for you.
I prefer a [flash memory installation on the USB](https://superuser.com/q/681/263).

<sup>ps: I think the "Try" window comes from the "`wubi.exe --cdmenu`" line in  "`autorun.inf`" of your LiveUSB.</sup>