# Can we install Linux on a portable hard drive and use that for booting?

Tags: linux, windows-vista

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Booting Linux off USB pendrives](https://superuser.com/questions/681/booting-linux-off-usb-pendrives)

Can we install Linux on a portable hard drive and use that for booting?  My laptop has Vista Professional installed, but I want to use multiple operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, provided that the BIOS is able to boot from a USB device (as has been the norm for the past 5 or so years) and has not been set disable that.

If it does not do so automatically, you may have to change settings or press some key early in the boot process.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, provided that your motherboard / BIOS supports this feature.

Another popular option for running multiple operating systems is to use a virtual machine manager, such as VirtualBox or VMWare Player.